# Find Next Number in SQL Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in a table that is integers but not in any common increments like: 1, 20, 30, 33

I thought this would be easy but all I want is to write a query that will return the next number, like if my current number is 1 how do I return 20?

Comment: This reads like a homework assignment question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Several options use an analytic and assign a row number to each value ordered such as `row_number() over (order by col)` and then select row number 2. another would be to `select max(col) from table where col > currentNumber` or `select top 1 from table where col > currentNumber order by col`  lots of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to select to first Min value that is greater than the one you have:

SELECT TOP 1 MIN(col) FROM table where col > currentNumber

The issue you have is that this is not in any good context (e.g. what is currentNumber? A variable? from another table?)

Comment: Yes let's say I have [1] as a variable...I would like to return [20] because that is the next step. Yes your query was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to select the next highest value... 
select column_name from table where column_name > current_value

Comment: To be safe you may want to sort the records.